# running sudo pip install times out

Tags: python, linux, pip

I'm having an issue when trying to run `sudo pip install ...` as it timesout when ever I try to install a package that way. I'm behind a proxy (OS is RHEL7) and I setup the proxy by running:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy:8099
export https_proxy=http://proxy:8099
```

if I do a `pip install ...`, that downloads but can't install because I'm not running as sudo. If I do `sudo pip install ...`, the `Collecting ...` part keeps giving me a network unreachable error.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the *.whl file and install the package passing the filename as parameter to pip. For example, the following line is trying to install BeautifulSoup.

```
python -m pip install beautifulsoup4-4.5.3-py2-none-any.whl
```

Also, you may download the compressed file, extract it and run the setup.py file inside of that folder.

```
tar -xzvf beautifulsoup4-4.5.3.tar.gz
cd beautifulsoup4-4.5.3
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted this answer to be a comment, but still. You have:

```
export https_proxy=http://proxy:8099
```

which is using **http**, but it should be **https** actually. Try editing this line.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others have posted, I found this link. It seems that there is a [known problem with pip and proxies](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1805). You also may have to use the `--proxy=<proxy address>` flag with your pip command.